# How to place a image above the footrule

Tags: pdftex, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

How to place a image above the footrule, Please see the below code

```
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%xxxxxxxxxx
%\newline xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\newline\vspace*{1pc}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{white-paper.png}
\color[RGB]{227,120,17}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
\hrule width \hsize height 2pt 
\end{minipage}\par}%

\lhead{How to place a image above the footrule}
\rhead{\TeX-SE}
\lfoot{\today}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Second}
\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]